# Trouble with SQL Server percentage calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for query to calculate percentage value can someone help me?

There are many example for single group by percentage calculation by I need group by for columns product and question.

Product column is from table1, question and response from table2

[image]

Comment: Thank you! percentage problem is fixed now.  One more question, If there is no response then DB doesn't return any NULL value, so if there no response like yes or no the I want to dispaly zero value in response count, how do I do that ?

Comment: I would suggest you post an answer for other users and ask a new question for the new issue that you are facing

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample data, I would suggest window functions.  These can be put into an aggregation query as:

```
select product, question, response
       count(*) as cnt,
       count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over (partition by product, question) as percent
from t
group by product, question, response
order by question, product, response desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *,
  100.0 * [Count(response)] / sum([Count(response)]) over (partition by Product, Question) Percentage
from tablename
```